# Процент от суммы по строке в сводной таблице

Tags: c#, excel

Возникла необходимость добавить еще одну сводную таблицу. Различные подсчеты делаются в значениях таблицы. У каждого "Значения" в параметрах есть "Операция" и "Дополнительные вычисления".
Первое я задаю так:

```
pivotTable.AddDataField(pivotField, "Имя", Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlCount);
```

А вот как доп вычисления задать?
В частности **% от суммы по строке**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было немного в другом месте, нужно добавлять это вычисление после создания поля:

```
pivotTable.AddDataField(pivotField, "Name", Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum).Calculation = Excel.XlPivotFieldCalculation.xlPercentOfRow;
```